# How to aggregate data only by the month part of a datetime field in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

So my model is like this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

And now I want to get the count of the blog posts by each month. The raw sql would look like:

```
SELECT COUNT (*), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM publication_date) AS month FROM blog GROUP BY month;
```

One solution I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997433/django-filtering-datetime-field-by-only-the-year-value), it suggests that getting a date list first then loop through it using `filter` for each iteration. I do not like it, I am looking for a way to get the result without using loop.

Comment: Querying by a range of dates should work, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range

Comment: The linked answer does not give me what I want. But thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: You want one blog per month ?

Comment: I want to get the posts count for each month.

Comment: Don't have Django handy, so OTTOMH: `Blog.objects.values('publication_date__month').order_by().annotate(Count('publication_date__month'))`

Comment: `Blog.objects.filter(publication_date__month = 4)` works, but `Blog.objects.values('publication_date__month')` does not. Error message: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'publication_date__month' into field

Answer (score 1):

You could use something to the effect of `Blog.objects.filter(publication_date__range=[start_of_month, end_of_month])` to get all items from between those two dates. See [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) for details.

Comment: But I do not want a range, I am looking for all the data in the database. The range only give me all the records between the dates, then I still have to use python to sort out the dates myself.

Comment: You may have to look into [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) if you're looking to do things the QuerySet API cannot natively handle. Especially if you already know what your SQL should look like.

Comment: Ye, after all the searching, I guess I will go with either using `extra()` or just raw sql. Thanks.